# Assume $F(x)=\frac{10}{x}$ is the summatory function of the arithmetic function $f$. Let $n=1,000,000$. Find $f(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume $F(x)=\frac{10}{x}$ is the summatory function of the arithmetic function $f$. Let $n=1,000,000$. Find $f(n)$

$f(n)=\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})$

Since $n=2^6*5^6$ I believe that $\mu(d) \not = 0$ for only $4$ divisors mainly $1,2,5,10$ is there a way to find out for sure given say a number with a larger set of prime factors?

So $\mu(1)F(\frac{2^6*5^6}{1})+\mu(2)F(\frac{2^6*5^6}{2})+\mu(5)F(\frac{2^6*5^6}{5})+\mu(10)F(\frac{2^6*5^6}{10})$

Then I would simplify that as much as I could. My main issue is finding out how many divisors I need to check.

Comment: The summatory function adds up all values, not just the values at the divisors, so I don't get how you are using that Mobius inversion formula there to express f in terms of F.

Comment: And what does "arithmetic function" mean in your context?

Comment: A function defined on the set of natural numbers, into $\mathbb{R}$ is called an arithmetic function.

Comment: Then my first comment remains: your first equation is wrong.

Comment: As I said, the summatory function is (usually) not over divisors but over all numbers. Check your notes for the definition of Mobius inversion and you'll see it doesn't apply here. (Unless you are using a different "summatory function".)

Comment: $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)$ this is what I have for summatory

Comment: You're talking about the sum of divisors function then, not the summatory function. In that case what you did is correct, and you just have to plug in the right values for the Mobius function and the evaluations of F. I don't see the problem. (If the number was more complicated to factor, the question wouldn't be given as an assignment.)

Comment: @HighSchool15 The number of divisors which are square free are $2^p$ where p is the number of primes in the factorization. Here you have to check $2^2$